# Testing project depending on database SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, testing

I have created a project, and was required to add a database connection lately.
For the database I am using SQL Server, and Entity Framework.
After altering the project so it depends on the database, my tests also depend on the database, thus affected by and affect the database content.
Should I isolate the tests from the database (or maybe create and connect to another database for the tests, but how)?
If so, what should be the most simple and correct practice to isolate the tests from the database?

Comment: Are you using Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control?

Comment: You could look at mocking framework such as MoQ or NSubstitute

Comment: Is the tests unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of connecting to a real SQL Server you could use a memory database such as [Effort for Entity Framework](http://entityframework-effort.net/)